# Evitar que los links de mi página se puedan abrir en otra página al dar doble click

Tags: javascript, jquery

He probado estos dos scripts para evitar que cualquier link de mi página web se pueda abrir en otra página al dar doble click. Ya comprobé que detecto el doble click, pero sigue abriéndome los enlaces en una página diferente.

Script 1:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*").dblclick(function (event)

            {
           return false;   
 });
</script>
```

Script 2:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*").dblclick(function (event)

            {
              event.preventDefault(); 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que se abran en otra página?

Comment: los enlaces se abren con un solo click, no con doble click.

Answer (score 2):

Apartando pequeños errores de sintaxis ambos ejemplos que publicaste funcionan, el manejo de los eventos funcionan en `chrome` mas no así en `firefox` ya que la variable global `event` no existe en `firefox`, en su defecto `firefox` pasa como ultimo parámetro la variable para el manejo de los eventos, ademas los `link` abren con un solo **click**, el siguiente código te muestra la forma correcta de como hacerlo.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("*").click(function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();

//  return false;       // también funciona
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com">google</a>
```

Comment: @Mariano disculpa es todo lo contrario, he modificado la pregunta.

Comment: ahora entendí a qué te estabas refiriendo... Un detalle más: si ya estás pasando al evento como parámetro de la función, ¿Es necesaria la primera línea como *failback*? Creo que `e.preventDefault()` te funcionaría en todos los casos (Chrome también lo pasa como parámetro), sin necesidad de recurrir al símbolo `event`.

Comment: Exacto! es por ello que nace el w3c para hacer de internet un estándar, el failback lo coloco por razones históricas (ya que viejas versiones de IE no pasan el evento como parámetro). hasta que internet no sea un estándar tendremos que lidear con este tipo de código.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. Entiendo los motivos históricos si hicieras la llamada directamente desde `addEventListener` o el viejo `attachEvent`. Sin embargo, al estar usando jQuery 2.1.1, desde jQuery se [*normaliza*](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event) al evento y al método `preventDefault()`, por lo que creo que no es necesario realizar ninguna comprobación extra, por lo menos hasta donde entiendo.

Comment: Estimado Mariano, programo desde los años 70, lamentablemente no puedo borrar todo lo que he aprendido en ese tiempo y comenzar desde 0, es por ello que encontraras en mis códigos cosas que podrían parecer incongruentes.

Comment: jajajaja... Muy buen comentario!!! Para aclarar, no es que te esté cuestionando, sino que en serio preguntaba para ver si **yo** me estaba pasando por alto algo que no sabía ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ambos scripts tienen errores de sintáxis. Falta poner }); al final, en ambos.

Corrigiendo la sintáxis al agregar lo anterior y asumiendo que insertaste el script para la inclusión de jQuery antes de dichos scripts, se evitará que los links (además de cualquier otro elemento que acepte el evento click o doble click) carguen la página al cual se refieren.

Para más claridad dejo un ejemplo de los cambios que debería hacerse a manera de ejemplo

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/__derton/pen/JLOJEQ)